Отображение маршрута на графах
пытаюсь сделать навигацию по круизному лайнеру на реакте. Сама карта будет графом, помещения это вершины, пути это ребра.
Пока что сделал просто демоверсию 
Но возник вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы ребра были ломаными и шли только по допустимому пути, как на картинке ниже, возможно нужно как то предварительно подготовить саму карту в редакторе по типу иллюстратора? 

Я бы просто расширил граф, и добавил вершин в коридорах,через которые пойдут найденные пути
